# Chrome-extension: Refresh popup.html to a new html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I've got my popup.html which is a login page. I'm wondering.. how would I (on successful login) redirect to a new html page (which is loaded in the area where `popup.html` was?) e.g When the user clicks the extension icon, `popup.html` comes up in the box, on successful login that box changes to a new html page other than `popup.html`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 22):

To permanently change a popup while it is closed:

```
chrome.browserAction.setPopup({popup: "new.html"});
```

If you want to temporary change a popup while it is still open:

```
window.location.href="new.html";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't think it would be so easy to do so, saved me a lot of hassle.

Comment: Bumping this answer up as it worked for me as well with only one change (my htmls are in a subfolder called "views", but I got a 404 error when using the full path (i.e "views/new.html"), so if the target file is in the same subfolder, just use the name as in this answer. Thanks serg!